# QML: How can the state of an item be assigned when the state of a different item changes? (How can I work around the state assignment limitations?)

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I have a fairly complex hierarchy of QML Components and Items. 
In a nutshell:

There is a parent **`GameGrid`** QML type which can do many different things.  The things it can do depend on what state the **`GameGrid`** is currently in. The state of the **`GameGrid`** can be changed by different functions depending on the current state of the **`GameGrid`**.   Whenever the **`GameGrid`** changes states, it automatically fires the code needed to handle everything for that state.

Sometimes, upon changing state , the code which is run by the **`GameGrid`** must set the **`GameGrid`** state  to a different value after it finishes processing.

-

The Result of this operation is:

> < Unknown File>: QML StateGroup: Can't apply a state change as part of a state definition.

### **How can I work around this limitation or properly arrive at the "play" state once the "init" state finishes working?**

I have tried connecting signals, functions, and assignments.

The only thing that works is to use a separate Timer item that changes the state afterwards.. 
This way is far too complex to realistically implement in a large codebase where there are many states and many changes to those states, at times asynchronously.

Here is the minimal code to reproduce this error

---

### GameGrid.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    id: gameGrid
    states: [
            State {
                name: "init"
                StateChangeScript {
                    script: {
                        console.log("Init actions");
                        gameGrid.state = "play";    /* causes the error */
                    }
                }
            },
        State {
            name: "play"
            StateChangeScript {
                script: {
                    console.log("Play Actions");  /* never does actions */
                }
            }
        }
        ]

    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: parent.state
    }

}
```

---

### main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    GameGrid {
        id: grid
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
    Component.onCompleted:  {
        grid.state = "init";
    }
}
```

---

### main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

  QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

  QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
  const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
  QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                   &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
    if (!obj && url == objUrl)
      QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
  }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
  engine.load(url);

  return app.exec();
}
```

---

### StateTest.pro

```
QT += quick

CONFIG += c++11

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS



SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc


QML_IMPORT_PATH =


QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =


qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define transitions in GameGrid for change state in state machine.

```
Item {
    id: gameGrid

    states: [
            State {
                name: "init"
                StateChangeScript {
                    script: {
                        console.log("Init actions");
                        gameGrid.state = "play";    /* causes the error */
                    }
                }
            },
        State {
            name: "play"
            StateChangeScript {
                script: {
                    console.log("Play Actions");  /* never does actions */
                }
            }
        }
    ]

    transitions: Transition { }
}
```